# Source for a story about mistakenly thinking Mashiach was here

Tags: messiah, wedding, story-identification, agada-stories-legends, showering-bathing

What is the story in the Gemara or Ein Ya'akov about the guy who ran into the streets when he thought the Mashiach was here, but really it was a wedding ceremony?

I can't find it anywhere.

The Rosh Yeshiva was telling us the story about a man who was bathing and heard music outside. He didn't hesitate, he knew it was Mashiach. So he hopped straight out of the shower and into the streets only to discover it was a wedding precession.

Comment: You’re sure this is a Gemara?

Comment: Did he happen to discover bouyancy?

Comment: I think it's agadata.